# In Laravel Factories, what is the difference from "state" and "defineAs"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

What is the difference, in Laravel's Factories, from using the method `state` and the method `defineAs`?

Is `state` just an extension of the base method and `defineAs` a whole different definition? Could you present some examples to make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The methods `state` and `defineAs` serve completely different purposes.

### `define` and `defineAs`

You register a factory for a model using the `define` method which you provide with a class and a callback. For example, if you are creating a factory for the `User` model then you would register it like this:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    // set values here
});
```

Then you would call the factory like so:

```
factory(App\User::class)->make();
```

However, sometimes you may wish to register a factory using a name instead of the class, so that you could call the factory like this:

```
factory('user')->make();
```

That's where `defineAs` comes in: `defineAs` accepts a class (e.g: `App\User::class`) *and* a name. For example:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, 'user', function (Faker $faker) {
    // set values here
});
```

`defineAs` isn't documented but you can find it in the [Eloquent source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php#L79).

---

### Factory States

[Factory States](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#factory-states) are used for generating models with a specific set of attributes:

> States allow you to define discrete modifications that can be applied to your model factories in any combination.

For example, your `User` model may have an additional `is_admin` field which determines if the user is an admin or not. You can create a state to allow for a user who is an admin to be generated through the factory.

First you define your state (where `admin` is the name):

```
$factory->state(App\User::class, 'admin', [
    'is_admin' => true,
]);
```

Then when generating your user you pass in the `admin` state:

```
factory(App\User::class)->states('admin')->make();
```

This means that you can have a single factory for your `User` model that supports many different *types* of User; you could create a state for banned users, or users who have a picture associated with their account, all within the same factory. This is extra beneficial because it means developers don't need to be concerned with the underlying structure when using factories, and if the underlying structure changes (e.g: `is_admin` becomes `administrator_at`) only the factory needs to be changed.

Comment: The correct usage is `factory(User::class, 'admin')->make()`, not `factory('admin')->make()`.

Comment: @MaksimIvanov You are absolutely right, but that is what he wrote. `factory('admin')->make()` is what you would wish to do and `factory(User::class, 'admin')->make()` is how you do it

Comment: Oh my confusion was About `->state & ->states` . thanks.

Comment: The defineAs method is removed in Laravel 7.x. See: 
[Eloquent source 7.x](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php)

Answer (score 2):

The answer before says that `defineAs` is like an alias or a shorthand name but it is wrong! If you make:

```
factory('user')->create(); //it won't work
```

`defineAs` and states are pretty much the same with a slightly difference.
In version prior to 5.2 states were called states https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#model-factories

So `defineAs` creates a different model type when you are creating a model, based in a raw model to set common attributes like this:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => str_random(10),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        'admin' => false,
    ];
});

$factory->defineAs(App\User::class, 'admin', function ($faker) use ($factory) {
    $user = $factory->raw(App\User::class);

    return array_merge($user, ['admin' => true]);
});
```

while `states` are doing the same but in a better fashion way like this:

```
$factory->state(App\User::class, 'address', function ($faker) {
    return [
        'admin' => true,
    ];
});
```

Or even without a callback, just an array:

```
$factory->state(App\User::class, 'address', [
    'admin' => true,
});
```

The other difference is that `define` fires an event (afterCreating) called once the object is persisted in database and `states` will fire an event `afterCreatingState`.
Also, you can create an object with multiple states like this:

```
factory(App\User::class)->states('admin', 'disable')->create()
```